# How can I toggle visibility and scroll to a target section in one click in Vue.js?

Tags: vuejs3, ref, vue-options-api

When switching between sections I want to toggle between hide / show and scroll the target section into view.

This code works but it takes two clicks instead of one to complete the process: first click toggles visibility and it takes a second click to actually scroll the target element into view. Try [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/two-click-issue-5o0kmw?file=/src/App.vue).

Why is that? How to solve?

Furthermore: advice on how to accomplish this without a separate show variable for each section and without having to pass source section ref is also welcome.

Vue.js:

```
<template>
  <section id="1" ref="1" v-show="show1" style="margin-bottom: 500px">
    <p>Section 1</p>
    <button @click="showScrollInto('1', '2')">Goto section 2</button>
    <button @click="showScrollInto('1', '3')">Goto section 3</button>
  </section>
  <section id="2" ref="2" v-show="show2">
    <p>Section 2</p>
    <button @click="showScrollInto('2', '1')">Goto home</button>
  </section>
  <section id="3" ref="3" v-show="show3">
    <p>Section 3</p>
    <button @click="showScrollInto('3', '1')">Goto home</button>
  </section>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      show1: true,
      show2: false,
      show3: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showScrollInto(from, to) {
    switch(from) {
      case "2":
        this.show2 = false
        break
      case "3":
        this.show3 = false
        break
      default:
        this.show1 = true
      }
    
    switch(to) {
      case "2":
        this.show2 = true
        break
      case "3":
        this.show3 = true
        break
      default:
        this.show1 = true
      }
      this.$refs[to].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'})
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
section {
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have changed the data controlling visibility, the DOM still needs to update. When you call `scrollIntoView()` immediately, there is still no node to scroll to.

You can wait until the update is finished using [`nextTick()`](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick):

```
await this.$nextTick()
this.$refs[to].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
```

or using a callback:

```
this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs[to].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" }))
```

Now the scroll event happens after the update when the element is available.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have tried various iterations and I found this.

In your sample code, you are trying to toggle the visibility and instantly scrolling to the section elements. However, this might take a little time to update the accordingly on the DOM.

I have used the [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) vuejs utility to wait for the DOM update and scroll to the section.

Here is the change

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs[to].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  });
```